# InteractionAlreadyReplied Error while sending a Modal, discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, modal-dialog, interaction

I am developing a bot using `discord.js` v14, so I was making a modal command but I found an error that I can't solve. Here is the code that I am using.

modal.js:

```js
const BOT = require("../../../handlers/Client");
const {
    ApplicationCommandType,
    Client,
    CommandInteraction,
    ModalBuilder,
    ActionRowBuilder,
    TextInputBuilder,
    TextInputStyle
} = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
  name: "modal",
  description: `ModalTest`,
  userPermissions: [],
  botPermissions: [],
  category: "Information",
  cooldown: 10,
  type: ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput,
  /**
   *
   * @param {BOT} client
   * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction
   * @param {String[]} args
   */
  run: async (client, interaction, args) => {


    const myModal = new ModalBuilder()
    .setCustomId("modal_1")
    .setTitle(`Modal Teste`);

    const username = new TextInputBuilder()
    .setCustomId("username")
    .setLabel("Username:")
    .setStyle(2)
    .setPlaceholder("Coloque seu nome")
    .setRequired(true)
    .setMinLength(4)
    .setMaxLength(10);

    const password = new TextInputBuilder()
    .setCustomId("password")
    .setLabel("Password:")
    .setStyle(2)
    .setPlaceholder("Coloque sua senha")
    .setRequired(true)
    .setMinLength(4)
    .setMaxLength(10);

    const username_row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(username);
    const password_row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(password);

    myModal.addComponents(username_row, password_row);

    await interaction.showModal(myModal);



    }
 }
```

events/modal.js:

```js
const { InteractionType } = require("discord.js");
const client = require("../index");

client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.type === InteractionType.ModalSubmit) {
        // code
        if (interaction.customId === "modal_1") {

            const username = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue("username");
            const password = interacrion.fields.getTextInputValue("username");

            if(username && password){
                await interaction.reply({
                    content: `Sua submissão foi enviada. \n\n UserName: ${username} \n Password: ${password}`,
                    ephemeral: true,
                })
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Here is the error code:

```js
[Error_Handling] :: Unhandled Rejection/Catch
Error [InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
    at ChatInputCommandInteraction.showModal (C:\Users\Rapha\Downloads\discord js procjet\PROJETINHO DIVINO QUE EU VOU TERMINAR EM NOME DE JESUS AMÉM\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:252:46)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\Rapha\Downloads\discord js procjet\PROJETINHO DIVINO QUE EU VOU TERMINAR EM NOME DE JESUS AMÉM\Commands\Slash\Information\modal.js:56:23)
    at BOT.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rapha\Downloads\discord js procjet\PROJETINHO DIVINO QUE EU VOU TERMINAR EM NOME DE JESUS AMÉM\events\interactionCreate.js:51:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'InteractionAlreadyReplied'
} Promise {
  <rejected> Error [InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
      at ChatInputCommandInteraction.showModal (C:\Users\Rapha\Downloads\discord js procjet\PROJETINHO DIVINO QUE EU VOU TERMINAR EM NOME DE JESUS AMÉM\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:252:46)
      at Object.run (C:\Users\Rapha\Downloads\discord js procjet\PROJETINHO DIVINO QUE EU VOU TERMINAR EM NOME DE JESUS AMÉM\Commands\Slash\Information\modal.js:56:23)
      at BOT.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rapha\Downloads\discord js procjet\PROJETINHO DIVINO QUE EU VOU TERMINAR EM NOME DE JESUS AMÉM\events\interactionCreate.js:51:13)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    code: 'InteractionAlreadyReplied'
  }
}
```

interactionCreate.js:

```js
const { ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require("discord.js");
const client = require("..");
const { cooldown } = require("../handlers/functions");
const { emoji } = require("../settings/config");

client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
  // Slash Command Handling
  if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
    await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true }).catch((e) => {});
    const cmd = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
    if (!cmd)
      return client.embed(
        interaction,
        `${emoji.ERROR} \`${interaction.commandName}\` Command Not Found `
      );
    const args = [];
    for (let option of interaction.options.data) {
      if (option.type === ApplicationCommandOptionType.Subcommand) {
        if (option.name) args.push(option.name);
        option.options?.forEach((x) => {
          if (x.value) args.push(x.value);
        });
      } else if (option.value) args.push(option.value);
    }
    interaction.member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(
      interaction.user.id
    );
    if (cmd) {
      // checking user perms
      if (!interaction.member.permissions.has(cmd.userPermissions || [])) {
        return client.embed(
          interaction,
          `You Don't Have \`${cmd.userPermissions}\` Permission to Use \`${cmd.name}\` Command!!`
        );
      } else if (
        !interaction.guild.members.me.permissions.has(cmd.botPermissions || [])
      ) {
        return client.embed(
          interaction,
          `I Don't Have \`${cmd.botPermissions}\` Permission to Use \`${cmd.name}\` Command!!`
        );
      } else if (cooldown(interaction, cmd)) {
        return client.embed(
          interaction,
          ` You are On Cooldown , wait \`${cooldown(
            interaction,
            cmd
          ).toFixed()}\` Seconds`
        );
      } else {
        cmd.run(client, interaction, args);
      }
    }
  }

  // Context Menu Handling
  if (interaction.isContextMenuCommand()) {
    await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true }).catch((e) => {});
    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
    if (command) command.run(client, interaction);
  }
});
```

I tried to followup the interaction but that didn't solve it, and I don't know what to do now

Comment: Can you show your `interactinoCreate.js` file as well?

Comment: it's on the post, i editted

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to show a modal, the truth is that you can't use `deferReply()` if you need to use `showModal()` as well (as far as I know). Since you used `deferReply()` in your interactionCreate.js file, this error popped out. So to fix it, all you need to do is remove that `deferReply()` and your code should work fine